# directory path as string: ensure DirectoryPathSeperator at the end of the string

Tags: c#, .net, path

Is there a method in .NET, which automatically appends a backslash at the end of a path which is a string?

Something like:

```
var path = @"C:\Windows";
path = Path.GetPathWithSeperatorAtTheEnd(path);
Console.WriteLine(path); 
// outputs C:\Windows\
```

What I currently do is:

```
if (!path.EndsWith(@"\")) path += @"\";
```

**EDIT:** What I'd like to achieve is, that if I append filenames to a path I don't need to worry about, that something like this happens. Or is there another approach than appending path and filename?

```
var fullFilename = path + filename;
// path    : C:\Windows
// filename: MyFile.txt
// result  : C:\WindowsMyFile.txt
```

Comment: Why do you need this? For directory access, this is not required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use: [`System.IO.Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Example:

```
var path = @"C:\Windows";
path = Path.Combine(path, "win.ini");
// path is @"C:\Windows\win.ini"
```